# Does mysql reprocess the same file when you do a LOAD DATA INFILE filename?

Tags: mysql

Is mysql intelligent enough not to re-process a file  via LOAD DATA INFILE if it hasn't been modified since the last run? Couldn't find a documentation on that .

Comment: Why would that be "intelligent"? It sounds like it would be wrong. There's nothing prohibiting duplicate rows in a table, unless it happens to have a unique key.

Comment: It does have a unique key.

Comment: That's just a special case, it can't assume it in general. And it needs to process it so it can produce a duplicate key error.

Comment: I have ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE thing in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will add the data again. That's my experience.

Edit:

I looked into this further and found the following: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

You can ignore rows with duplicate keys. So if your entire file hasn't changed then, in effect, it will be ignored.

> The REPLACE and IGNORE keywords control handling of input rows that duplicate existing rows on unique key values:
>
> If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row. See Section 13.2.7, “REPLACE Syntax”.
>
> If you specify IGNORE, input rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are skipped.
>
> If you do not specify either option, the behavior depends on whether the LOCAL keyword is specified. Without LOCAL, an error occurs when a duplicate key value is found, and the rest of the text file is ignored. With LOCAL, the default behavior is the same as if IGNORE is specified; this is because the server has no way to stop transmission of the file in the middle of the operation.